# Visual Studio 2022 debugger shows JS strings as HEX

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

At some point, an update of VS 2022 (or something else) caused the debugger to start showing JavaScript strings as HEX. For example, if I hover over a variable containing "on" it shows 6f6e. Is there a setting that changed? I have tried restarting VS, removing the hidden .vs folder, rebuilding, etc. I have not tried re-installing, but I am currently applying the latest update to see if that will fix it.

Anyone have any idea why it suddenly started doing this? Or better yet, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I am quite dense sometimes. In the variable or watch window, if you right-click, there is an option to show "Hexidecimal display". Not sure when that got ticked on, but it activates it for hovering too.